# What's the cleanest way to turn a TraversableOnce[T] into a Multiset-like or Histogram-ish Map[T, Int]?

Tags: scala, multiset

I want to convert a Traversable[T] to a Map[T, Int] histogram with counts.  I'd like the result to be an immutable Map that matches what I would get by doing:

```
traversable.groupBy(_).mapValues(_.length)
```

But it looks like this isn't spacewise or timewise efficient...since `groupBy` maintains a reference to every element in the traversable, this has poor performance on large traversables with a small set of unique keys.  I really want something more like this:

```
def histogram[T](ts : Traversable[T]) : Map[T, Int] = {
  val map = new collection.mutable.HashMap[T, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
  ts.foreach { map(_) += 1 }
  map.toMap
}
```

Is there a library method that gives me this result (and ideally, works well with the parallel collections)?

Comment: There isn't anything there by default, and yours is as good as anything for brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my extension, very similar to your suggestion:

```
implicit final class RichIterable[A](val it: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def histogram: Map[A, Int] = {
    var res = Map.empty[A, Int] withDefaultValue 0
    it.foreach { elem =>
      res += elem -> (res(elem) + 1)
    }
    res
  }
}
```

Not necessarily the fastest solution, but concise :)

Answer (score 1):

`t.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) { (acc, i) => acc.updated(i, acc(i) + 1) }`

Comment: sorry, my version isn't generic but you can easily make it so

Answer (score 0):

I would consider pimping traversables with your histogram function. Make an implicit class which adds "toHistogram[T]" to traversables. I don't think that functionality is there in the standard library.